# N-мерный класс Vector на С#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Проблемы решения задания начались еще с момента прочтения ТЗ.

Задание:

> Создать класс Vector (математический вектор в n-мерном пространстве). Описать нужные конструкторы.

На просторах интернета выдает создание класса Vector'а в смысле как массива. Мне нужно класс именно математического вектора. Но все бы ничего если бы нужен был вектор конкретно в 2х или 3х мерном пространстве, а по ТЗ в n-мерном пространстве. То есть изначально неизвестно какой размерности будет вектор, и каким образом проводить операции типа сложения и умножения.

Comment: Ну так n-мерный вектор это и есть по сути массив с n элементами. Я бы просто хранил внутри класса массив длины n, а "математическость" описал методами и свойствами

Comment: На C# обычно не пишут свои библиотеки, а как максимум делают обёртки над уже существующими

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно быть просто, размерность задается при создании вектора.

```
public class MyVector
{
    private readonly double[] _values;
    public int Size => _values.Length;

    public double this[int index]
    {
        get => _values[index];
        set => _values[index] = value;
    }

    public MyVector(int size)
    {
        _values = new double[size];
    }

    public MyVector(params double[] values)
    {
        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));
        _values = values;
    }

    public static MyVector operator +(MyVector left, MyVector right)
    {
        if (left.Size != right.Size)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Размеры векторов не совпадают.");
        var result = new MyVector(left.Size);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Size; i++)
        {
            result[i] = left[i] + right[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"<{string.Join(", ", _values)}>";
    }
}
```

Пользоваться можно так

```
var left = new MyVector(1, 2, 3);
var right = new MyVector(4, 5, 6);
var sum = left + right;
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Вывод а консоль

```
<5, 7, 9>
```

*В этом решении есть ряд мелких допущений с точки зрения оптимизации и целостности, но все они сделаны умышленно в пользу упрощения кода.*

---

Дальнейшее развитие класса с увеличением количества операторов может привести к резкому росту объема кода, поэтому приведу пример сразу для 4 математических операций. Разобью каждую операцию на 2 метода и использую делегаты. Бонусом добавил функцию `Dot`.

```
public class MyVector
{
    private readonly double[] _values;
    public int Size => _values.Length;

    public double this[int index]
    {
        get => _values[index];
        set => _values[index] = value;
    }

    public MyVector(int size)
    {
        _values = new double[size];
    }

    public MyVector(params double[] values)
    {
        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));
        _values = values;
    }

    private static void EnsureSize(MyVector left, MyVector right)
    {
        if (left.Size != right.Size)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Размеры векторов не совпадают.");
    }

    private static MyVector Apply(MyVector left, MyVector right, Func<double, double, double> func)
    {
        EnsureSize(left, right);
        var result = new MyVector(left.Size);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Size; i++)
        {
            result[i] = func(left[i], right[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static MyVector operator +(MyVector left, MyVector right)
    {
        return Apply(left, right, (l, r) => l + r);
    }

    public static MyVector operator -(MyVector left, MyVector right)
    {
        return Apply(left, right, (l, r) => l - r);
    }

    public static MyVector operator *(MyVector left, MyVector right)
    {
        return Apply(left, right, (l, r) => l * r);
    }

    public static MyVector operator /(MyVector left, MyVector right)
    {
        return Apply(left, right, (l, r) => l / r);
    }

    public static double Dot(MyVector left, MyVector right)
    {
        var m = left * right;
        return m._values.Sum();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"<{string.Join(", ", _values)}>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто открыли мне глаза! Невероятно благодарен!